# Alternatives to using OnFling

Tags: android, gesture, onfling

So I'm working on an app in which I have a bar that the user should be able to kind of "pull open". It should expand when the user swipes up. I've been thinking about how to do this. I know I could probably use the `OnFling` method in `GestureDetector` on the layout and detect a vertical fling, but this would probably be quite fiddly for the user and bulky in code. I feel there must be alternative ways of doing this. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [ViewDragHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html). It's a component meant to help move around child views within a ViewGroup. A very cool project that uses it and already does what you are trying to accomplish is called [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). You can check out it's source or use it directly.